# How to wait for <table> to be created before loading controls within

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic table for Users in roles that is created via jquery once a ajax call is completed. The table is not just data it also adds a dropdown to one column so the user's role can be changed.

How do I wait until the table is done being created to attempt to load the dropdown with their options and and then set selected?  If I open developer tools and step through it, it works, I am assuming b/c there is enough time for the table to be drawn.

Help needed on resolving the issue, open to suggestions if this is a dumb way to do all of it :)

The table

```
          <div class="col-md-9 ">
                <div class="card border-light rounded p-5">
                    <table id="grdUsers" class="table table-sm" style="width: 80%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th class="d-none">UserID</th>
                                <th class="d-none">RoleID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The ajax call

```
function GetUserRoles() {

return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:44365/api/userroles'
});
```

Build the table

```
function LoadApplicationUsers(appID) {
    $('#grdUsers').DataTable().clear();
    $('#grdUsers').DataTable().destroy();
    GetUserRoles().done(function (users) {
        $.each(users, function (index, user) {
            if (user.applicationID == appID) {
                $("#grdUsers tbody").append(`
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteuser"> X </button></td>
                <td class="d-none userID">${ user.userID}</td>
                <td class="d-none userID">${ user.roleID}</td>
                <td>${ user.username}</td>
                <td><select class="roles"></select></td>   
                <td>${ user.roleName}</td>
            </tr>
            `);
            }
        });
        $('#grdUsers').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
        });
    });

}
```

Load the dropdowns

```
function LoadRolesDropdown(appID) {
    GetRoles().done(function (roles) {
        $.each(roles, function (index, role) {
            if (role.applicationID == appID) {
                $(".roles").append(`
                 <option value="${role.roleID}"> ${role.roleName}</option>
            `);
            }
        });
        $(".roles").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
}
```

Called on change of application dropdown at top of page

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddlApplication', function () {
    var appID = $("#ddlApplication option:selected").val();
    LoadApplicationUsers(appID);
    LoadRolesDropdown(appID);
});
```

Comment: Where or when is LoadRolesDropdown called? I don't see it being called anywhere in the code. Why not call it after the .each() loop that draws the table? What error or issue are you facing?

Comment: I am doing the same call in document.ready as in ddlApplication change.

The table loads but the dropdowns do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the LoadRolesDropdown() after the LoadApplicationUsers() but inside LoadApplicationUsers() there is an ajax call that runs asynchronously, takes its time.

Move the LoadRolesDropdown inside the LoadApplicationUsers and call it after the each() loop.

```
function LoadApplicationUsers(appID) {
    $('#grdUsers').DataTable().clear();
    $('#grdUsers').DataTable().destroy();
    GetUserRoles().done(function (users) {
        $.each(users, function (index, user) {
            if (user.applicationID == appID) {
                $("#grdUsers tbody").append(`
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteuser"> X </button></td>
                <td class="d-none userID">${ user.userID}</td>
                <td class="d-none userID">${ user.roleID}</td>
                <td>${ user.username}</td>
                <td><select class="roles"></select></td>   
                <td>${ user.roleName}</td>
            </tr>
            `);
            }
        });
        $('#grdUsers').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
        });
        LoadRolesDropdown(appID);
    });    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Any thoughts on the code overall?  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `LoadRolesDropdown()` function after DOM has finished it's rendering. In jQuery you can do this way,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  LoadRolesDropdown(WITH_APP_ID);
})
```

Comment: Doing that already, dropdowns will not load
`
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".chosen").chosen();
        LoadApplicationDropdown();
        var appID = $("#ddlApplication option:selected").val();
        //LoadApplicationUsers(appID);
        //LoadRolesDropdown(appID);
    });
`